# Loading information from file C++

Tags: c++, file, variables, authentication

I have a program that loads information from a file into player class variables. All works fine except for the last variable playerdamage..

```
void Player::loadplayer(std::string name)
{
    std::ifstream UserFile;
    UserFile.open(name + ".txt");

    if (UserFile.is_open())
    {
        while (UserFile.good())
        {
            getline(UserFile, playername, ';');
            getline(UserFile, playerpass, ';');
            UserFile >> playercash;
            UserFile >> playercoords;
            UserFile >> playerdamage;
        }
    }
    UserFile.close();
}
```

Here are the file contents (with playerdamage being the last one):

```
Allura;Password123;5.00;0.0;10.00
```

But if I log in and type 'stats':

[image]

It all loads correctly except for the damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appens if you use only get line ?

```
        getline(UserFile, playername, ';');
        getline(UserFile, playerpass, ';');
        getline(UserFile, playercash, ';');
        getline(UserFile, playercoords, ';');
        getline(UserFile, playerdamage);
```

if you want integer or double value convert your data after getline call :

To convert string to int :

```
atoi( str.c_str() ) // C++ 98

std::stoi( str ) // C++ 11
```

To convert string to double:

```
atof( str.c_str() ) // C++ 98

std::stod( str ) // C++ 11
```

so you get something like this:

```
        string playercoordsString;
        getline(UserFile, playercoordsString, ';');
        playercoords = std::stod(playercoordsString);
```

Comment: Apparently, getline doesn't work for ints or doubles.. Would make life a whole lot easier if it did!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are separating the values with a ';' where the >> operator works on consecutive characters from the file and doesn't know that a semicolon is your delimeter.

The simpliest and fastest thing to fix the problem is to skip a single character from file after each call. So you would get code like this:

```
UserFile >> playercash;
UserFile.ignore(1);
UserFile >> playercoords;
UserFile.ignore(1);
UserFile >> playerdamage;
```

This way all the conversions are still handled by the stream itself - which is good, less coding for the developer.

Another approach would require more work. Basically according to docs the ifstream operator>> works as described (in short)

> Extracts and parses characters sequentially from the stream to
>   interpret them as the representation of a value of the proper type,
>   which is stored as the value of val.

The variables in your examples are of unknown type, if they where specified with your own type then you could overload the ifstream *operator>>*